# Create account on "external" database

Tags: mysql, database, api, external, account

So, here is the thing. The user downloads a package (a kind of wordpress 2.0), and go to index.php to install the database and create necessary files. Now, let's say my framework is called CoolFramework. I want the user to create a CoolFramework account before installing the files. How can I access the CoolFramework database from the user's server without giving him further access to the data?

I mean, I want his account to be created on my database (coolframework) but isn't it kinda dangerous ? The user could access a lot of sensible data... How do I limit the access ?

Thank you for your help,

Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `GRANT` syntax. You are able to grant a user specific permissions on a specific database and restrict it to certain IP.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html.

The idea would be that you would only give that user permissions to access the `coolframework` DB and not any of the other DBs.

Something like

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON coolframework.*
TO 'user'@'123.234.34.23'
IDENTIFIED BY 'my_password';
```